# MAMP PRO not showing all MAMP database

Tags: mysql

I was earlier using MAMP and Now switched to MAMP PRO. I used to use MAMP mysql as root default user and having lots off database as that user. If i start MAMP and go to terminal with mysql command and do `show databases;` then it show me all databases. But if i start MAMP PRO and goto terminal and do `show databases;` then it show me only 4 databases `mysql, information_schema, performance_schema` and one db which is common for both MAMP and MAMP PRO. How can i use those existing DB on MAMP under MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used MAMP or even heard of it until I read this question, but if both MySQL installations are the same base version of MySQL you can probably fix this by copying the databases from one installation's data directory to the other.

First, run the following in MySQL in each MySQL installation:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

That will tell you where the databases are for each installation.

Next, stop both MySQL installations. This is important because if they are running, you won't be able to make a consistent copy of the data.

Next, make a backup of the MAMP Pro MySQL installation's datadir. You should be able to do this by running the following in a shell:

```
cp -a <MAMP Pro datadir> <new backup directory>
```

Now copy the old databases to the new:

```
cp -a <MAMP datadir> <MAMP Pro datadir>
```

Finally, start the MAMP Pro instance and confirm whether the databases are present.

You could also do a backup and restore with `mysqldump`, but a copy is probably simpler especially since this is only for development.